# How to filter multiple dataframes in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of dataframes and I would like to apply the same filter to all of them without having to copy paste the filter condition every time.

This is my code so far:

```
df_list_2019 = [df_spain_2019,df_amsterdam_2019, df_venice_2019, df_sicily_2019]

for data in df_list_2019:
    data = data[['host_since','host_response_time','host_response_rate',
             'host_acceptance_rate','host_is_superhost','host_total_listings_count',
              'host_has_profile_pic','host_identity_verified',
             'neighbourhood','neighbourhood_cleansed','zipcode','latitude','longitude','property_type','room_type',
             'accommodates','bathrooms','bedrooms','beds','amenities','price','weekly_price',
             'monthly_price','cleaning_fee','guests_included','extra_people','minimum_nights','maximum_nights',
             'minimum_nights_avg_ntm','has_availability','availability_30','availability_60','availability_90',
              'availability_365','number_of_reviews','number_of_reviews_ltm','review_scores_rating',
              'review_scores_checkin','review_scores_communication','review_scores_location', 'review_scores_value',
              'instant_bookable','is_business_travel_ready','cancellation_policy','reviews_per_month'
             ]]
```

but it doesn't apply the filter to the data frame. How can I change the code to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The filter (column selection) is actually applied to every DataFrame, you just throw the result away by overriding what the name `data` points to.

You need to store the results somewhere, a list for example.

```
cols = ['host_since','host_response_time', ...]
filtered = [df[cols] for df in df_list_2019]
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you write `var = new_value`, you do not change the original object but have the variable refering a new object.

If you want to change the dataframes from `df_list_2019`, you have to use an `inplace=True` method. Here, you could use `drop`:

```
keep = set(['host_since','host_response_time','host_response_rate',
             'host_acceptance_rate','host_is_superhost','host_total_listings_count',
              'host_has_profile_pic','host_identity_verified',
             'neighbourhood','neighbourhood_cleansed','zipcode','latitude','longitude','property_type','room_type',
             'accommodates','bathrooms','bedrooms','beds','amenities','price','weekly_price',
             'monthly_price','cleaning_fee','guests_included','extra_people','minimum_nights','maximum_nights',
             'minimum_nights_avg_ntm','has_availability','availability_30','availability_60','availability_90',
              'availability_365','number_of_reviews','number_of_reviews_ltm','review_scores_rating',
              'review_scores_checkin','review_scores_communication','review_scores_location', 'review_scores_value',
              'instant_bookable','is_business_travel_ready','cancellation_policy','reviews_per_month'
             ])

for data in df_list_2019:
    data.drop(columns=[col for col in data.columns if col not in keep], inplace=True)
```

But beware, pandas experts recommend to prefere the `df = df. ...` idiom to the `df...(..., inplace=True)` because it allows chaining the operations. So you should ask yourself if [@timgeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61790866/3545273) cannot be used. Anyway this one should work for your requirements.